# Playwright + CodeceptJS - Unable to find element by Xpath

Tags: xpath, puppeteer, codeceptjs, playwright

In my code I can usually find an element by Xpath and perform actions like shown below

```
await I.fillField('//*[@id="edit-name"]','user1');
```

I am seeing the following error when I perform the following action. As the **ID is dynamically created**. Is there a recommended approach to tackle this type of elements?

```
await I.fillField('//*[@id="crmUiId_1"]','SomeTextHere');
```

**Error:**

```
 **TypeError: Cannot read property '$$' of null
      at findElements (node_modules/codeceptjs/lib/helper/Playwright.js:2087:18)
      at Playwright._locate (node_modules/codeceptjs/lib/helper/Playwright.js:822:12)**
```

Associated HTML:

```
    <div crm-ui-field="{name: 'caseTypeDetailForm.title', title: ts('Title')}" class="ng-isolate-scope crm-section"><div class="label">
  <label crm-ui-for="caseTypeDetailForm.title" crm-depth="1" crm-ui-force-required="" for="crmUiId_1"><span ng-class="cssClasses"><span ng-transclude=""><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Title</span></span><span crm-ui-visible="crmIsRequired" class="crm-marker ng-isolate-scope" title="This field is required." style="visibility: inherit;">*</span></span></label>
  <!-- ngIf: help -->
</div>
<div class="content" ng-transclude="">
      <input crm-ui-id="caseTypeDetailForm.title" type="text" name="title" ng-model="caseType.title" class="big crm-form-text ng-pristine ng-scope ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" required="" id="crmUiId_1">
    </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The issue here is actually the ID "crmUiId_1" is dynamically generated. Instead I tried xpath with ng-model="caseType.title" but it doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: That selector is not in the html you show. Also, just use `#crmUiId_1`

Comment: Sorry updated with correct html now.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make sure you wait for it:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#crmUiId_1')
await page.fill('#crmUiId_1', 'whatever')
```

Otherwise the page might still be loading.

Comment: Playwright auto-waits for elements before the fill, so this will not be required with Playwright. [Relevant docs](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.4.2&path=docs%2Factionability.md&q=)

Comment: I guess that's true but I'm not sure I trust it.